# Comparing words with scandinavian characters

Tags: java, netbeans, special-characters, equals

My program reads with Scanner class few words from a file and compare them to users output. My editor is NetBeans and OS Windows 7. I first ran the program in NetBeans and had no problems. When I ran it in the command prompt, scandinavian characters (ä, ö, å, Ä, Ö, Å) didn't display correctly. Well, I tested and gave different parameters for Scanner, like ISO-8859-1 but it didn't help. Finally, I gave UTF-8 for it and characters also display well. But I got a new problem. I use equals method to compare two words. But now it doesn't "work". Though the words should be equals method returns false. If I haven't any character set for Scanner the program works well in NetBeans but not in the command prompt. So what can I do and why doesn't equals method work? Should I create my own comparing method or something?

```
public void readingWordsFromFile(String textfile){

try{
    File f = new File("WordLists\\" + textfile + ".txt" );
    Scanner l = new Scanner(f, "UTF-8");

    try{

    int i = 1;
    while( l.hasNext() ){

        String temp = l.nextLine();

        words.put(i, temp);

        i++;
    }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
    }
    finally{
    l.close();
    }
}
catch (Exception e){
}
}
```

Edit: "Solved". The answer doesn't relate to character sets. Files contained BOM because I had accidentally saved them with Notepad. So now I use again Notepad++ and everything is fine. : )

Comment: Do you mean the windows command prompt? If so, the windows cmd [is not UTF8 by default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how/388500#388500). The netbeans console is UTF8, so it works properly.

Comment: You should provide sample code with demonstration of how do you use `scanner` and encodings

Comment: BTW, what does command `chcp` prints out in windows command promt?

Comment: I added a piece of code. It printed: Active code page: 850.

Answer (score 0):

1. `equals` will not work when comparing two strings in different encondings - in terms of internal `string` representation - they are absolutelly different pieces of data
2. you should try set proper encoding for scanner, when using it in windows `cmd`. Try use command `chcp` in `cmd` to see which codepage is used inside it.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows cmd [is not UTF8 by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how/388500#388500). The netbeans console is UTF8, so it works properly.

In fact, if you type `chcp` in the console and press enter, you should see

```
Current active code table is: 850
```

Which is the ASCII Latin 1 charset.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever possible use UTF-8, often one can pass StandardCharsets.UTF_8. For Swedish ISO-8859-4 is more suitable than the mentioned ISO-8859-1.

However one problem with Unicode is that an accented letter occurs as one Unicode code point (letter inclusive the accent), and as separate Unicode code points: ASCII letter and "combining diacritical mark" (the accent). For a text normalisation one might use `java.text.Normalizer`.

Usage of encodings in java suffer from many method and constructor signatures having an overloaded version *without* encoding defaulting to the operating system (or set) encoding.

In your case it looks like the latter. A Scanner without specified encoding, a FileReader/FileWriter, InputStreamReader, new String.